# Rounding down to the nearest 100

Tags: c, math

I have an int that I need to round down to the nearest 100.

As an example:

91 would be rounded down to 0

101 would be rounded down to 100

199 would be rounded down to 100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
main()
{
    int a=0;
    scanf ("%d", &a)
    a= ( a/100) * 100;
    printf ("Result:%d", a);
}
```

The above code will satisfy your requirement.

Comment: @Will - Guess somebody has done your homework - but life is not full of free lunches - perhaps your tutor reads this site as well

Comment: @EdHeal This was not homework or anything of the sort. I am an 18 year old kid who just left high school, am on a gap year, and I wanted to learn how to program.

Answer (score 2):

you take the input as an Int datatype and simply divide input by 100 and muliply it by 100. you'll get your answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
    int a=0;
    printf ("Enter no:");
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    a= ( a/100) * 100;
    if (a>=0)
    printf ("Result:%d", a);
    else printf("Result:%d", (a-100));
```

This will ensure that your code works for negative integers as well.